# Should use add or remove migration ,or do changes in existing migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Want to know the right step to do migration from following two options.
 When changing the migration, should I only use `rails g migration add_column_to_tablename`?

Or I can change directly migartion file without any migration command?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I consider best practices:

- If you haven't performed the migration, you can edit it then migrate.
- If you've already migrated, but it's the most recent migration, you
  can do `rake db:rollback STEP=1` to quickly roll it back, change it,
  then `rake db:migrate` again.
- If the migration is far enough in the history of your app, it's best
  to add a new migration so you have a history of what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

If my last migration hasn't been deployed to production, then i rollback and edit the migration file directly.  If it has been deployed then I add a new migration file to make the correction.

Essentially in development mode I edit the existing files.  Some people choose to always create a new file, but this can create tons of tiny migrations that are difficult to sift through later.  For me this is the best solution